# Extract data from a tag using python

Tags: html, json, python-2.7, rest, http

I am trying to retrieve a data from tag element via python rest calls using the following code:

```
url ="https:abac.com?tag=id:34" 
headers = {"Authorization": token}
response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers).json()
```

When i use above code, am getting "Bad Request Error". However, if i omit the tag in the url as below, am getting a valid json output

```
url ="https:abac.com"
```

I sorted some ways to retrieve tag data via python and found Beautiful Soup as an option. But, for some reasons, am not allowed to install this package on my work system. Could someone please share your thoughts on the same?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it doesn't look like a valid URL to me

Comment: i just provided an example.... i didn mention the actual url... but, there is no problem with my url since it was working perfectly with postman app.